# Can't launch webdriver selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently working on a project that involves downloading CSV files from a website using Selenium. I've successfully automated this process on Windows, but I'm encountering issues when transitioning to Ubuntu Server.

Here are the details of my setup:

- Google Chrome v120.0.6099.109
- ChromeDriver 120.0.6099.129
- Python virtual environment with Selenium 4.16.0

However, when I run my application, I encounter the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pscv/web_server/scripts/ACTUALIZADOR.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
  ...
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/local/bin/chrome-linux64/chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

And here's the relevant code snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--headless')

options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

options.add_argument('--download.default_directory=/home/pscv/downloads')

options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"

service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chrome-linux64/chrome")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

I've tried various solutions, including those suggested by ChatGPT, but I'm still facing this issue.

Comment: Does your server have a GUI. Because as far as I know Ubuntu Server doesn't come with a GUI. And what is the link that you are scraping?

Comment: Just the command terminal. I’m scraping a private health care database.